# How to write a python code which copies a unique column from an output file to a .csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have an data file which is output after I run some calculations, and I would like to copy two columns from the output file to a new csv file, to save me the time of having to copy, paste, and get rid of the useless information between. I've posted a bit of the output below:

Fitted charges ordered as within the cube file

```
Charge 1 of type 6 = -1.058011

Charge 2 of type 6 = 0.063732

Charge 3 of type 6 = -1.648329

Charge 4 of type 6 = -0.426020
```

Charge 5 of type 8 = 0.708180

I only wish to copy the type numbers (i.e 6) and the value for the charges to separate columns in a csv file. Any links or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please paste some code that shows youve tried something. Also paste a snippet of your csv file

Comment: What is your question? You gotta be more specific than "how to write a python code." We aren't gonna do the work for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways you can do this. The best option is probably the python [module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) for .csv operations.
An example taken from the docs is:

```
import csv
with open('some.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerows(someiterable)
```

Hope this helped.